# PhpStorm configuration for automatic creation of the class namespace use statement like in ZendStudio

Tags: zend-studio, phpstorm

I like ZendStudio feature when after typing class name and pressing "Enter" it automatically adds namespace use statement into the head of the script file.

Is it possible to do the same in the PhpStorm IDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this has been there all the time, or if it a new addition but it can be done already.

On my case, you get on top of the class that you want the `use` imported and you press `alt+Enter`. A popup allowing you to select which namespace you want to import pops up.

You can see a more graphical explanation here:

[PHP Storm Tricks: Add your USE Statements Automatically!](http://www.craftitonline.com/2012/06/php-storm-tricks-add-your-use-statements-automagically/)

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to *disable* it (it's native and enabled by default now) and found this SO thread.

For people like me, here's where the setting:

> Editor > Auto-import > PHP - Enable auto-import in namespace scope

Answer (score 0):

Please vote http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/WI-1362

Comment: Not implemented yet. So sad ;(

Answer (score 0):

In PHPStorm 6.0.3 on Mac (and presumably other platforms) you should follow the advice given by @Savageman. It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Go to "Settings" (Ctrl+Alt+S) > "Code Style > PHP" (I'm assuming you're using PS 3.0)

Comment: Can't find any reference about use statements in "Code Style".